# Help with one interview question --expected length of numbers drawn

Tags: probability

Randomly draw numbers from 1 to n without replacement and $x(n)$ is the nth number you draw. Continue drawing numbers if $x(n) > x(n-1)$ and stop if $x(n) < x(n-1)$.

Calculate the expected length of numbers you draw.

Comment: from what distribution?

Comment: The distribution is the uniform(1,N). However, the question is not fully stated. Do you mean "... and stop if $x(n) < x(n-1)$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Brain-teaser: What is the expected length of an iid sequence that is monotonically increasing when drawn from a uniform \[0,1\] distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/350923/brain-teaser-what-is-the-expected-length-of-an-iid-sequence-that-is-monotonical)

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming that we're uniformly drawing numbers (without replacement), and stop when we *explicitly* see that the currently drawn number is smaller than the previously drawn number. That means, if we draw $N$ first, we still draw another number and see if it is smaller than $N$, which is going to happen for sure. With this setup, it's certain that we'll draw numbers at least $2$ times. This way, the problem has a beautiful answer, however the OP should still clarify the question to help other readers who can benefit.

Let $X$ be the number of draws in this experiment. Since $X$ is nonnegative and integer we can express the expected value as $$E[X]=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} P(X>k)$$
Here, $P(X>k)=\frac{1}{k!}$ because for number of draws to be bigger than $k$, the first $k$ draws must be sorted, which happens with $\frac{1}{k!}$ probability no matter what $N$ is. Expanding the sum yields:
$$E[X]=1+1+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(N-1)!}$$

Notice that this converges to $e$ as $N\rightarrow\infty$

Comment: The question says to keep drawing if the current number is larger (while you say to stop in that case) -- you may want to correct your statement in the first sentence.

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b ,I had flipped the question before solving since it has the same answer, bur forgot to rephrase it back.